# Find the maximum of hits within a session in BigQuery (legacy SQL)

Tags: session, google-bigquery

In BigQuery using data from GA, I am trying to find the pagetype (based on pagepath) with the maximum number of hits within a session for each session for a user. This will be used to determine which pagetype had the most activity for a session (I want only one, hence max).

Using the row number to assign rank for each pagetype within a session and filtering for rank 1 works for one user. When I try to replicate that for the bigger dataset (~400GB), I get the 'Resources exceeded....' error.

I'm new to BigQuery and would appreciate any tips to optimize this code.

```
SELECT
    userid,
    sessionid,
    pagetype,
    hits
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, sessionid ORDER BY sessionid ASC) rnk
    FROM (
      SELECT
        userid,
        sessionid,
        pagetype,
        COUNT(1) AS hits
      FROM
        [xxxxxxx] WHERE
       GROUP BY
        userid,
        sessionid,
        pagetype
      ORDER BY
        sessionid,
        hits DESC ) )
  WHERE
    rnk = 1
```

Comment: Why use legacy SQL if you are new to BigQuery? Using standard SQL would mean that you can use ARRAY_AGG with ORDER BY and LIMIT, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), you can write a query such as:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  first_session.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(
      STRUCT(userid, sessionid, pagetype, hits)
      ORDER BY sessionid ASC LIMIT 1
    )[OFFSET(0)] AS first_session
  FROM (
    SELECT
      userid,
      sessionid,
      pagetype,
      COUNT(*) AS hits
    FROM `xxxxxxx`
    GROUP BY
      userid,
      sessionid,
      pagetype
  )
  GROUP BY userid, sessionid
);
```

This builds a struct with the relevant columns for each group and selects only the first one, as determined by `sessionid`.